# Custom Django form doesn't validate

Tags: django, django-forms

I've been working for some days in a Django validation problem using a form. After days looking out how to resolve it, I find that data isn't being validated. My Django form doesn't return any kind of error (even if i put the error tags in the template).

Instead of using {{ form }}, I decided to do a custom form, creating an HTML code and putting manually all the Django form fields. Before doing this and using simply `{{ form }}` the form worked correctly

Here I pass you fragments of my code:

template.html:

```
    <form action="/next_direction/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.errors }}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

            Elementa: {{ form.elementa }}<br/>
            Elementb: {{ form.elementb }}<br/>
            Elementc: {{ form.elementc }}<br/>

            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

    </form>
```

Now, in forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from alta_tecnologias.models import Tecnologia
import datetime
from django.forms.extras.widgets import SelectDateWidget
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class AltaTecnologias(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(AltaTecnologias, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['fecha'].initial = datetime.date.today()


    elementa = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    elementb = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    elementc = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
    fecha = forms.DateField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(AltaTecnologias, self)
            return self.cleaned_data

    class Meta:
            model = Tecnologia
```

And in views.py:

```
from django import shortcuts
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import Context, loader, RequestContext
from alta_tecnologias.forms import AltaTecnologias
from alta_tecnologias.models import Tecnologia
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect

@login_required
def alta_tecnologias(request):
        if request.POST:
                form = AltaTecnologias(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save()
                        return HttpResponse("OK")

        context = Context({'is_auth': str(request.user.is_authenticated()), 'form': AltaTecnologias()})
        template = loader.get_template("alta_tecnologias.html")
        return render(request, 'alta_tecnologias.html', context)
```

I did many changes on my code following other answers I found on the web, but anyone seems to work on my code.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're always re-instantiating the form before passing it to the template, so the errors from the posted version will be lost. Instead, only instantiate one time for each of GET and POST.

```
    if request.POST:
            form = AltaTecnologias(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    form.save()
                    return HttpResponse("OK")
    else:
        form = AltaTecnologias()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'alta_tecnologias.html', context)
```

Not that you don't need to create a Context object, and your call to get_template is completely unnecessary, as both of these things are done by the `render` function. Also note you can access `{{ user.is_authenticated }}` directly in the template, so there's no point in passing it in explicitly. Plus, as Lukas states, your override of `clean` does nothing, so you might as well remove it.

Comment: This was the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AltaTecnologias, self)
        return self.cleaned_data
```

should be:

```
def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AltaTecnologias, self).clean()
        return cleaned_data
```

anyway, I don't see any point in overriding clean method, when you don't do any checks against your data.